# Output 48MHz system clock on a GPIO pin other than MCO pin on STM32F030

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, clock, gpio, stm32f0

I want to output the max 48MHz clock signal of STM32F030 to drive another subcircuit. The problem is the chip STM32F030F4P6 (TSSOP-20 package) I prefer to use a GPIO because the MCU doesn't have the MCO pin (PA8). Is there a way around?

Comment: It would better enable us to solve your problem if you could tell us *why* you can't or don't want to use PA8/MCO.

Comment: @hexafraction The package of STM32F030F4P6 doesn't expose PA8 pin. Of course I can use other package that has PA8 pin, but the BOM is higher. I only use a few GPIOs and TSSOP-20 package is sufficient except for the absence of PA8.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all of your answers. It seems 48MHz signal output is not possible for this TSSOP-20 package without MCO/PA8 pin. I will use another package that has this pin.